# Regular expression for matching all file names with 888 except those containing 888/444, 888/447, or 888/405?

Tags: ruby, regex

We're having trouble creating a regular expression to match all file names containing 888 except those containing 888/444, 888/447, or 888/405.

We tried using character classes and negating them, but they didn't seem to work. Advice?

Here's what we tried: `/888.[^(444)|(447)|(405)]/`

We're using Ruby 1.9.3. Thanks!

Comment: assume the strings are of arbitrary length, and the patterns we're matching for can appear anywhere in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^a-z]
```

Matches a character that isn't in the range `a-z`. In your attempt, you've put an alternation group inside the character class, but it simply doesn't work like that. Instead, you need to use a negative lookaround assertion (presuming Ruby supports these):

```
/^888(?!(44[47]|405)).*$/
```

To break this down:

```
^           # Anchor to start of string
888         # Match 888
(?!         # Negative lookahead
  (         # Alternation group
    44[47]  # Match 444 or 447
    |       # ...or...
    405     # 405
  )
)
.*          # Match any number of any characters
$           # Anchor to end of string
```

Note that the part that says "Match any number of any characters" will be restricted by the negative lookahead, so that 444, 447 and 405 will *not* match, as per your requirements.

So, this will match `888123`, `888 foo bar`, but will not allow `888444` or `888447`, etc.

---

**EDIT** To match the requirement of appearing anywhere within the string:

```
/888(?!.*4(4[47]|05)).*/
```

i.e., Matches any 888 followed by anything (including nothing), except 444, 447 or 405.

Comment: It's fine if you're matching the beginning of the string

Comment: Fair enough: Looks like that comment appeared while I was writing my answer :P

Comment: I know... I assumed the 444, 447 or 405 could appear anywhere after the 888

Answer (score 3):

Use negative lookahead:

```
888.(?!(444)|(447)|(405))
```

Comment: This will match '888/444.888.' for example

Answer (score 3):

Advice:

```
%r"888(?!/444|/447|/405)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go with:

```
/^(?!.*888\/(444|447|405)).*888.*/
```

I don't believe there's a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something very specific in mind like what you have currently, why not match the inverse and then filter out items that match?

Like so:

```
/(888\/444)|(888\/447)|(888\/405)/
```

which matches those that you don't want, use this and eliminate accordingly.